# statsd/graphite vs google analytics server side

Tags: google-analytics, graphite, statsd

What is the difference b/w statsd/graphite vs google analytics (sever-side)? Are the two same/similar?

I am trying to find out when would I use statsd/graphite and when would I use google analytics server side?

I am asking on the server-side ( not web client )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't close. Google Analytics gives you a plethora of user information based on clicks, page visits and even the geographic location. And then it has a hefty dashboard that good enough for 99% users.

Statsd, on the other hand cannot do any of this on it's own, and needs little scripts here and there, to send it metrics, which it will in turn forward to Graphite. Collecting the bunch of information that Google analytics does is certainly possible, but a long-tedious road.

Unless you have some events that these out-of-the-box solutions can't offer analyzing, don't go for it.

Answer (score -2):

Google analytics is based on javascript loaded into the browser. It's a fair approximation of what's going on with your server but it shouldn't be confused with engineering.

If you want to know things about how your systems are operating, then your time is a worthy invest in graphite, carbon or statsd.